# What's the meaning of "as your concern allows"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-requests

What is the meaning of "as your concern allows" in this context:

> Keep in touch as your concerns allow.

The above sentence was preceded by the sentence:

> We seem to be out of sync in reading each other's mind.

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

The context seems too loose to allow any external reader a real understanding about the matter. A full paragraph would be more than useful.

Answer (score -1):

I think it probably means keep the relation(or maybe connection) as long as you are comfortable and you are not upset about anything.